# Directed graph with $15$ edges and $16$ nodes

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, directed-graphs

Does this kind of graph have a name other than it is an directed graph?

[image]

Does it have a property or characteristics? Visually I see $15$ edges and $16$ nodes. I want to learn more about graphs, but especially this one. I left out the numbers in the graph, but each node (vertex) has an unique number.

What can be said about this graph only to have the visuals in mathematics?

Comment: A tree graph...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your digraph has the property that, if you start at any node and follow the arrows, you always end up in the same place. (For a finite digraph, that's equivalent to saying that it's acyclic and has a unique sink.) Such a digraph is called an *in-tree* or an *anti-arborescence* among other things.. With all the arrows reversed, it's called an *out-tree* or an [*arborescence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)) etc. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, thank you.